Is it possible to log into Stack Overflow using a passkey?
I am curious if there is support for passkeys for Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange. If not, is it on a roadmap?

Never even realized there were Web APIs for that.

I'm pretty sure that's a no, unless you use it to log into an authentication provider like Google.

Well I would argue that it is actually a "yes", because Stack Overflow supports logging in through federated means which will support passkeys.

Besides logging in with a federated authentication provider, username/password authentication is also enabled. Passkeys would add a nice 2FA layer on that while not having to rely on federated authentication providers.
